# Running parallel tests with RemoteDriver + SeleniumGrid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

**What am I doing**

I am trying to run parallel java selenium-webdriver test with Selenium-Grid which was integrated in `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar`. I intend to run multiple firefox instances to perform different cases at the same time. BTW, I won't use TesgNG or JUnit.

**What I have done**

Convenient for you guys I will provide just a portion of my code.

I have a Firefox resolver here.

```
public class FirefoxResolver implements Resolver{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Override
        public void connectHub() {
            DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

            dc.setBrowserName("firefox");

            dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);


            try {
                URL url = new URL(BrowserFactory.HUB); //Here I am sure I connect to a correct hub

                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, dc);
            } catch(ANYEXCEPTION HERE) {

            }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriver() {

        return driver;
    }
}
```

And here I have a Main Runnable

```
public class MainRunner implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Resolver r = BrowserFactory.getInstance().getBrowserResolver(
                        browser);

                r.connectHub();

                driver = r.getDriver();
     /************************************************
     Use driver to do something then.
     /************************************************

     **Finally here I use a driver.quit() to shutdown the driver created in current thread. I have also tried driver.close()**

    }
    }
```

Once triggered, my main processor will start a new thread to run MainRunner. I have debugged and found that there are actually different instance 'driver' generated.

Also I did research:

You should use Selenium Grid when you want to do either one or both of following:

Run your tests against different browsers, operating systems, and machines all at the same time. This will ensure that the application you are testing is fully compatible with a wide range of browser-O.S combinations.

Save time in the execution of your test suites. If you set up Selenium Grid to run, say, 4 tests at a time, then you would be able to finish the whole suite around 4 times faster.

**Issue**

When I ran two cases at the same time using firefox, they seem share the same session and interacted each other. Whether I deploy the node in different machine or not.  Neither one of the cases would be successful. It seems that if one of the cases have finished and invoke `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`, the other one is unable to continue performing. Here is the stack trace info if I use `driver.close()`:

> Exception in thread "Thread-26" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>
> Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
>   System info: host: 'J.Lyu', ip: '192.168.6.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
>
> Command duration or timeout: 1.51 seconds
>
> Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
>   System info: host: 'J.Lyu', ip: '192.168.6.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>   Session ID: 2b73c6e8-f601-4259-9646-9a53241fe074
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=2b73c6e8-f601-4259-9646-9a53241fe074, version=40.0.3, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
>           at com.milanoo.qa.runtime.module.MainRunner.run(MainRunner.java:167)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
>   System info: host: 'J.Lyu', ip: '192.168.6.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>   Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
>   System info: host: 'J.Lyu', ip: '192.168.6.71', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Can any one help with is? Thanks so much and if you want to more information please let me know.

**Update 2015/10/12 11:51**

I have tried that even if I don't use any shutdown command(quit close or dispose), the issue still exists.

I have checked the log message of the hub then found that the later performed one will always success while earlier one be failed(Whether I start just one node or two nodes AND whether they are in different machine(VM or RM)). Seems the something related to the earlier one was covered by the later started one. But so far it hasn't output any Exception. The earlier one just blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I finally got the point. I was using *@Autowired* which provided by Spring to mark my Runnable(MainRunner). And as per my research the class which annotated by @Autowired is a singleton. It's all my faults and thanks for you guys attention.